AppleTV Infinite horizontal CollectionView (scroll indefinitely ) implementation problems
Introduction:
Im attempting to create an Collection that scrolls indefinitely + leave the focus position on the left ( or right ) of the collection view, as can be seen in the video below:

I found this approach ( that works really good for mobile ) that basically shifts the content offset of the collection ( the git for this project is here ), I tried to implement it on tv
Problem:
While implementing the above solution on tvOS i had to take into account that with the content offset I need to change the next cell to focus to the start of the collectionView, Because when scrolling to the last cell item that is not considered a buffer and the offset switch occurs, the focus still continues to the next cell,
and while I tried to handle it, this is how it looks:

As you can see, when moving from cell number 5 to 0 the offset change occurs but the focus continues to the cell at index 6 and then goes back to cell number with the number 0, making the focus "flicker". I tried to block the next focus item and redirect it to cell number 0 but it never managed to make it as smooth as a regular focus change
on top of that there are 2 more bugs:

as you can see in the second video i made the CollectionView short, because for some reason the CollectionView breaks when its the width of the screen ( I tried to add more items to the list but it didn’t help )

scrolling backwards doesn’t work ( the solution for the mobile it to make the CollectionView bounce on scroll, allowing it to have contentOffset < 0 to make the opposite ContentOffset switch ( i didn’t try to solve this problem yet as I want it to work first in one direction )


My full code ( on main(storyboard) I added a CollectionView with height:300, width:1300, running it on simulator AppleTV 4k):
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

private let models: [Model] = [
    Model(text: "0", backgroundColour: .systemBlue),
    Model(text: "1", backgroundColour: .systemYellow),
    Model(text: "2", backgroundColour: .systemRed),
    Model(text: "3", backgroundColour: .systemGreen),
    Model(text: "4", backgroundColour: .systemPink),
    Model(text: "5", backgroundColour: .systemPurple),
    //        Model(text: "7", backgroundColour: .systemPink),
    //        Model(text: "8", backgroundColour: .systemGreen),
    //        Model(text: "9", backgroundColour: .systemYellow),
    //        Model(text: "10", backgroundColour: .systemGreen),
    //        Model(text: "11", backgroundColour: .systemBlue),
    //        Model(text: "12", backgroundColour: .systemBlue),
    //        Model(text: "13", backgroundColour: .systemYellow),
    //        Model(text: "14", backgroundColour: .systemRed),
    //        Model(text: "15", backgroundColour: .systemGreen),
    //        Model(text: "16", backgroundColour: .systemPink),
]

//additional variables:
let buffer = 10
var totalElements: Int = 0
var myNextIndexPath: IndexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CollectionViewCell.identifier)
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    
}

override var preferredFocusEnvironments: [UIFocusEnvironment] {
    return [(collectionView.cellForItem(at: myNextIndexPath) as! CollectionViewCell)]
}
    }

    extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate{

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    totalElements = buffer + models.count
    return totalElements
}

func indexPathForPreferredFocusedView(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> IndexPath? {
    return myNextIndexPath
  }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell else{
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
    let currentCell = indexPath.row % models.count
    cell.configure(with: models[currentCell])
    
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 150, height: 180)
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldUpdateFocusIn context: UICollectionViewFocusUpdateContext) -> Bool {
    guard let nextFocus =  context.nextFocusedIndexPath else { return false }
    if models.count < nextFocus.item {
        myNextIndexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: nextFocus , at: .left, animated: true)
        return false
    }
    return true
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didUpdateFocusIn context: UICollectionViewFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
        guard let previousIndexPath = context.previouslyFocusedIndexPath,
              let nextIndexPath = context.nextFocusedIndexPath else {
            return
        }

        // Get the previously focused cell and animate it back to its original size
        if let previousCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: previousIndexPath) as? CollectionViewCell {
            coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({
                previousCell.transform = .identity
            }, completion: nil)
        }

        // Get the newly focused cell and animate it to a larger size
        if let nextCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: nextIndexPath) as? CollectionViewCell {
            coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({
                nextCell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.1, y: 1.1)
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    myNextIndexPath = nextIndexPath
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: nextIndexPath, at: .left, animated: true)
}


    }

    extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate{
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let itemSize = collectionView.contentSize.width/CGFloat(totalElements)
    
    if (itemSize.isNaN) { return } // was added for the tv version because its called
    
    if scrollView.contentOffset.x > itemSize*CGFloat(models.count) {
        collectionView.contentOffset.x -= itemSize*CGFloat(models.count)
        myNextIndexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
        self.collectionView.setNeedsFocusUpdate()
        self.collectionView.updateFocusIfNeeded()
    }
    if scrollView.contentOffset.x < 0  {
        collectionView.contentOffset.x += itemSize*CGFloat(models.count)
    }
}
    }

    struct Model{
let text: String
let backgroundColour: UIColor
    }

    class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
static let identifier = "cell"

private let label: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.textColor = .white
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .medium)
    return label
}()
override init(frame: CGRect){
    super.init(frame: frame)
    contentView.addSubview(label)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    label.frame = contentView.bounds
    contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    label.text = ""
}

func configure(with model: Model){
    contentView.backgroundColor = model.backgroundColour
    label.text = model.text
}
    }

I will appreciate any help or maybe a better solution
Thank you.
